# igraph graph.adjacency weighted=NULL

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I am trying to get the weighted degree and unweighted degree distribution of a matrix with weighted edges in igraph. I used the graph.adjacency function such as

```
newMatrix<-graph.adjacency(matrix, weighted=NULL, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
```

But the weighted argument is not given me the result I expected.
For a 3x3 matrix for example with the following values:

```
    [,1][,2][,3]
[1,]  1   2   2
[2,]  2   2   0
[3,]  2   0   3
```

I would expect with the argument weighted=NULL and diag=FALSE an adjacency matrix such as:

```
    [,1][,2][,3]
[1,]  .   1   1
[2,]  1   .   .
[3,]  1   .   .
```

So the degree distribution for unweighted edges vector would be degree(2,1,1). Nevertheless the function is returning a weighted matrix. The returning adjacency matrix is:

```
    [,1][,2][,3]
[1,]  .   2   2
[2,]  2   .   .
[3,]  2   .   .
```

I have tried to change the weighted argument to TRUE and de modes to min, max... but the results always give me back a weighted matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When `weight=NULL` and `mode=undirected`, `graph.adjacency` interprets the i,j entry of the (symmetric) adjacency matrix as the number of edges between i,j.  You can change this interpretation by changing the `mode` parameter (see the documentation).

To count each edge only once (which appears to be what you want to do), you can just rescale the input matrix

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,2,2,2,0,2,0,3),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
mscaled <-ifelse(m>=1,1,0)
newMatrix<-graph.adjacency(mscaled, weighted=NULL, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
```